# Spring MVC @RequestMapping opening a different jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a SpringMVC application, and I need it to open a completely different jsp. If I am validating a transaction (in "editing.jsp"), and the data passes all editing steps, and it gets written successfully to the database, I need to redirect to display "success.jsp". Both jsp files exist in the WEB-INF/jsp directory. Ideally I'd like to also return some data to display in that page. This seems like it should be simple to do, but so far, I have not been able to discover how to change my @RequestMapping method do do it.

Perhaps I need to somewhere set up a mapping between "success.jsp" and a new different url?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does _the data passes all editing steps_ mean? When does this happen? If you want to render a JSP, return a corresponding view name from the handler method (with whatever model attributes are appropriate to "display").

Comment: "The data passes all editing steps" means the data is acceptable, and I write it to the database.  This is done in an ajax call.  At the end of that, I want to display a completely different page, the "success.jsp" page.  I have tried "return success.jsp" but there has to be more to it than that.

Comment: please share the relevant source

Comment: The source is not relevant.  When I return from the Controller, how do I tell it to open a new page?  I need it to open the "success.jsp" page.  How do I code that?  if the @RequestMapping method ends with "return success.jsp" that does not work.  If the method ends with "return new ModelAndView("success.jsp")" that doesn't work either.  How do I code this?